# Using CASE to update when not already set

Tags: sql-server-2008, case

I have a simple table that appears as follows:

```
+--------+-------+----------+
| client | value |  status  |
+--------+-------+----------+
| A      |    A1 | positive |
| B      |    B2 | neutral  |
| C      |    C3 | negative |
| D      |    B2 | neutral  |
| E      |    A1 | positive |
+--------+-------+----------+
```

The status field relates directly to the value field, however the value field is changed automatically so I use a select statement to show which status fields need updating as follows:

```
SELECT client, value, status, 
    CASE value 
        WHEN A1 THEN postive 
        WHEN B2 THEN neutral 
        ELSE negative 
    END AS new_status
FROM table
WHERE status <> CASE value 
                    WHEN A1 THEN postive 
                    WHEN B2 THEN neutral 
                    ELSE negative 
                END
```

This works fine but I've never liked how the exact same CASE appears in both the SELECT and WHERE clause. Is there a better way to write this SELECT to only show what status fields need updating?

Comment: You can use a derived table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   
    SELECT  client,
            value,
            status,
            CASE value
            WHEN 'A1' THEN 'postive'
            WHEN 'B2' THEN 'neutral'
            ELSE 'negative'
            END AS new_status
    FROM    table                                                                                           
    ) AS t                                                                                              
WHERE   status <> new_status
```

Comment: Wow that was easy! Didn't even think to do that... Thanks!